# Is the teambuilder a separate queue?

Tags: league-of-legends

The Teambuilder recently got introduced to the live servers of League of Legends. I really like the idea and all but there is one thing that interests me:

Is it a separate queue? Do you get matched only against players that also use the teambuilder or can you play against players that queued up in blind pick?

Comment: It's a good idea, but what I noticed is that there a 100 open groups with 3 or 4 people and it needs very long to get a full party. Until I was able to play the first game, it took 10 minutes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hey according to the [forum post](http://forums.euw.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?p=13575345) the queue is a seperate one:

> 2) Will Team Builder replace other queues?
>   a) Initially, Team Builder will be an entirely separate queue. We're looking forward to feedback from players and will use that feedback to determine whether this type of Champion Select is a good fit for modes like Ranked Mode but for now, we're focused on improving the Champion Select experience as an independent queue experiment.

Comment: Can confirm; it's a separate option under 5v5 / Summoner's Rift. (So that mode now has Teambuilder, Normal Blind, Normal Draft, and Ranked)